# Count workdays in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel Sheet from a work logging software that contains a column
with dates, a second one with Tasks and a third one with a name.

Basically I see that "John" worked 3 hours on task A, and 5 hours on task B on a given day.

If there were many short tasks on a certain day, there might be 8 line items for "John" that day.

There are also 100 different workers on this sheet.
-> 30 Days * 5 tasks * 100 Workers is about 15000 lines per month.

My desire is to see how many days a worker was working at all in a given month"

"Find unique dates for worker X and sum them up"

I can use 
`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A7000,A2:A7000&""))`
 to find unique days in column A (By the way this seems to be limited to 7000 lines!!! 7001 will give "0" as the result although cells A7000 and A7001 have an identical date.

But now I only want to count the date if worker A is in column B...

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF(A2:A7000,A2:A7000&"")) * (A25:A7000 = "John"))`

This seems to be syntactically correct but always returns  "0"

Hhhmmm?

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change it to an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B7000 = "John",1/COUNTIFS(B2:B7000,"John",A2:A7000,A2:A7000)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

If you want to use SUMPRODUCT then you need to change it a little:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7000= "John"),1/COUNTIFS(B2:B7000,"John",A2:A7000,A2:A7000))
```

Sumproduct will ignore the errors when split with a comma.

Also, Both formulas where tested with up to 8000 and had no problems returning the correct answer.